# Atom text editor undo changes too much

Tags: atom-editor

When I use the undo feature in my Atom text editor, it will often go back too far in the state for my liking in just one undo operation.

Is there a way to set the sensitivity of the undo command?  I'd be happier with a character-by-character buffer, if possible!

Comment: Apparently this has been around for a while: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2689. I'm curious why others do not find this behavior disconcerting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer here: https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/2689

This is caused by Vim mode.

`undo` will undo everything in the current `insert`.  It's expected behavior for Vim, not a bug.

Disabling Vim mode is the only solution, apparently.